# Stop xcode before run?

Tags: ios, xcode, installation, itunes, breakpoints

I have a bug which occurs because an user installs the app but doesn't run it. He adds some files via itunes and only then runs the installed app.

So I need to repeat the same actions. Breakpoints should help but I don't know where to insert them. NOTE: `main.m` is not the starting point so I can't just place breakpoint in it - some code is executed before it (maybe because of submodules).

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the scheme, in the Run Info find the Launch section at the bottom and select `Wait for executable to be launched`.

Now, when you run,  Xcode will install the app and wait. You can then do whatever you want with the device / iTunes and when you manually start the app Xcode will kick in.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your app from the "Product" menu without running.  Then open Xcode's "Devices" window, select your target device, and drag your app from the "Products" section of the Project navigator to the Installed Apps part of the device window.  That should get you an installed build that hasn't been launched.